# In T-SQL is there a way to say that if this parameter is equal to "XYZ" then use "XYZ" but if not return all?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm currently creating stored procedures on the SQL server by using linked servers, "OPENQUERY" statements, and temporary tables.  My goal is to have one source that will be consumed by multiple third party sources so that everyone is viewing the same data.

Where I'm running into my problem is that some instances need a specific where clause where others don't need this where clause.  Is there a way to Declare this where clause equal to something that nullifies that where clause if it's blank but use the where clause if it's populated?  I've tried making the parameter equal to "%", "%?%", etc. but nothing seems to work.

I would also like to point out that this is an Oracle Database that I'm pulling from on a Microsoft SQL Server.  My code is below and the parameter `@WINS` is what I'm trying to nullify if left blank:

```
DECLARE @query_start DATETIME;
DECLARE @query_end DATETIME;
DECLARE @query_wins NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @query_start = '7/1/2020';
SET @query_end = '7/15/2020';
SET @query_wins = 'F6666';


DECLARE @START_DATE NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@query_start,105)
DECLARE @END_DATE NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@query_end,105)
DECLARE @WINS NVARCHAR(MAX) = @query_wins

 
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'
       SELECT 
              * 
       FROM   
              OPENQUERY
              (
                     PDB, 
                     '' SELECT 
                           T1.WELL_NUM
                           , D2.WELL_NAME
                           , T1.DAILY_RDG_DATE
                           , T1.GROSS_OIL_BBLS
                           , T1.GROSS_GAS_MCF
                           , T1.GROSS_WTR_BBLS
                           , T1.TUBING_PRESS
                           , T1.CASING_PRESS
                           , T1.GAS_LINE_PRESS
                           , T1.CHOKE,T1.CHOKE_SIZE AS CHOKE2
                           , T2.GAS_PROD_FORECAST
                           , T2.OIL_PROD_FORECAST
                           , T2.WTR_PROD_FORECAST
 
                           FROM
                             (PDB.T003031 T1 
                                     INNER JOIN WINS.DW_ANORM_ROWL@WINP_DBLINK.WORLD D2 
                                           ON T1.WELL_NUM = D2.WINS_NO 
                                           AND T1.CMPL_NUM = D2.CMPL_NO)
                                     LEFT JOIN PDB.T000057 T2 ON T1.WELL_NUM = T2.WELL_NUM 
                                           AND T1.CMPL_NUM = T2.CMPL_NUM 
                                           AND T2.FORECAST_DATE=T1.DAILY_RDG_DATE
 
                           WHERE
                                  D2.HOLE_DIRECTION = ''''HORIZONTAL''''
                                  AND D2.ASSET_GROUP = ''''Powder River Basin'''' 
                                  AND T1.DAILY_RDG_DATE > TO_DATE(''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@START_DATE,105)  + ''''',''''DD-MM-YYYY'''') - 2
                                  AND T1.DAILY_RDG_DATE < TO_DATE(''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@END_DATE,105)  + ''''',''''DD-MM-YYYY'''') 
                                  AND D2.OPER_NON_OPER = ''''OPERATED'''' 
                                  AND T1.WELL_NUM = ''''' + @WINS + '''''
                ''
              )
 
'
 
PRINT @SqlCommand
 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
 
CREATE TABLE #temp (
       WELL_NUM NVARCHAR(MAX)
       , WELL_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
       , DAILY_RDG_DATE DATETIME
       , GROSS_OIL_BBLS FLOAT
       , GROSS_GAS_MCF FLOAT
       , GROSS_WTR_BBLS FLOAT
       , TUBING_PRESS FLOAT
       , CASING_PRESS FLOAT
       , GAS_LINE_PRESS FLOAT
       , CHOKE1 FLOAT
       , CHOKE2 FLOAT
       , GAS_PROD_FORECAST FLOAT
       , OIL_PROD_FORECAST FLOAT
       , WTR_PROD_FORECAST FLOAT
)

PRINT @SqlCommand

INSERT INTO #temp
 

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SqlCommand
 
SELECT 
       WELL_NUM
       , WELL_NAME
       , DAILY_RDG_DATE
       , ISNULL(GROSS_OIL_BBLS,0) AS 'GROSS_OIL_BBLS'
       , ISNULL(GROSS_GAS_MCF,0) AS 'GROSS_GAS_MCF'
       , ISNULL(GROSS_WTR_BBLS,0) AS 'GROSS_WTR_BBLS'
       , ISNULL(TUBING_PRESS,0) AS 'TUBING_PRESS'
       , ISNULL(CASING_PRESS,0) AS 'CASING_PRESS'
       , ISNULL(GAS_LINE_PRESS,0) AS 'GAS_LINE_PRESS'
       , ISNULL(CHOKE1,0) AS 'CHOKE1' 
       , ISNULL(CHOKE2,0) AS 'CHOKE2'
       , ISNULL(GAS_PROD_FORECAST,0) AS 'CHOKE2'
       , ISNULL(OIL_PROD_FORECAST,0) AS 'OIL_PROD_FORECAST'
       , ISNULL(WTR_PROD_FORECAST,0) AS 'WTR_PROD_FORECAST'
    

FROM #temp

ORDER BY
    DAILY_RDG_DATE ASC

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an optional parameter like this in SQL Server

```
WHERE ISNULL(@parameter,column_name) = column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I abstract your problem properly, you're trying to apply different filtering logic based on the value of a field.

You might consider using a cursor for this, iterate over the table and apply if / else as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to compose the SQL command as a string? Maybe you're only doing that to share the code here, hopefully?

Anyway, It sounds like this would work for you:

```
WHERE (T1.WELL_NUM = @WINS OR @WINS IS NULL) AND
...other conditions...
```